# What is the integrity property inside yarn.lock file?

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg, yarn-lock.json

For some reason, the command `yarn` is modifying the file `yarn.lock` with a new property to every dependency: `integrity`.

Git diff:

> +integrity sha1-zgBCgEX7t9AxwWp7+DV4nxU2arI=

I couldn't find documentation about it so my question is - What is it?

Comment: try this: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2979

Comment: It's the product of a SHA512 hash, converted to binary, and encoded in base64: `sha512sum <tarball> | awk '{ print $1 }' | xxd -r -p | base64 -w 88`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is used to detect whether the files have changed since the author originally published them.  If the SHA hashes don't match because of file modifications, the integrity check fails.

The author pushes their code to a repository, and this field is used to make sure that what the repository sends out is identical to what the author produced.

The idea of an integrity field is described here:
https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-subresource-integrity/#resource-integrity

Comment: Thanks for this info. Is this documented anywhere in yarn?

Answer (score 4):

the integrity was used to verify that versions and hashed values of the package contents in the project’s `package.json` match those in yarn’s or package's lock file. This helps to verify that the package dependencies have not been altered.

you can check this in [yarn check --integrity](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/check/)